# How to generate a File

Tags: c#, vb.net

I want to generate a .txt file when user clicks a button. The issue is I am not sure how to do it? I would like to have it so it uses this format:

```
00000012 <-- at the very start of the text file
2011 11 29 <-- Year 2011, Month 11, Day 29 (the year month and day based on my PC)
0010 or 0054 <-- this is a random number randomly one of these 2 numbers...
123456 <-- Time, Hour 12, Minutes 34, Seconds 56.
```

so when I open the text file it should be something like this: 
00000012201111290054123456

I am new to C#. I was able to accomplish this on visual basic with this:

```
Public Class Form1

    'declare new random object

        Dim r As New Random

        Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'declare string + set initial value
        Dim fileString As String = "00000012"
        'add formatted date
        fileString &= Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd")
        'add random 0010 or 0054
        fileString &= New String() {"0010", "0054"}(r.Next(0, 2))
        'add random 6 digit number
        fileString &= r.Next(0, 1000000).ToString("000000")
        'write file
        IO.File.WriteAllText("C:\Program Files\Code\maincode\maincode.txt", fileString)
        End Sub

        End Class
```

I have decided to change the last random 6 generation to the time instead. How to do it in C#?

Comment: So.. What do you have in your c# code so far, and what actual problem did you run into?

Comment: this is a VB.NET, not C#

Comment: Have you looked at the [File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.aspx) object on MSDN ?

Comment: @codesparkle he said he's new to c#, he's managed to do it in VB with that code.

Comment: Those who shouting about vb. Read question again: `I am new to C#. I was able to accomplish this on visual basic...`

Comment: @codesparkle "I am new to C#. I was able to accomplish this on visual basic with this: <VBSample>" i think that makes sense

Comment: He knows this is VB, he wrote it. I back BugFinder's question, what's the actual problem? You write as if you didn't even know C# syntax (because conversion of this code from VB to C# is trivial)

Comment: Agreed. You should show what you have tried otherwise - we are not code converters.

Comment: Why don't you use one of the various [VB to C# converters](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to solve your problem would be to use `String.Format`, which [works pretty much the same way](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx) in VB.NET as it does in C#.

Before getting to that, though, it's worth addressing some issues with your VB.NET code; fixing these will make your C# code a lot better as well:

- Your `Random` instance, `r`, is declared at the form (module) scope, but you only use it inside your `Form1_Load` procedure: it's a good idea to always keep your variable scope as limited as possible, in other words keep your declarations "as close to" the usage as you can;
- While on the subject of `System.Random`: do keep in mind that this actually creates a quite predictable (time-based) series of numbers, so it shouldn't be used for anything security-related (that's what `System.Security.Cryptography.RNGCryptoServiceProvider` is for). Your usage of Random isn't very strong anyway, and I'm not sure of your actual use case, but this is always something to keep in mind;
- You use comments that almost literally describe what your code does, which is rather pointless: only add comments to add additional insight into *why* your code does the things it does, not *how*;
- Strings in .NET are immutable, which means that each time you use the `&` operator, you create a new string, leaving the old one to linger around until garbage collection kicks in. That gets really expensive after a while: instead, [learn about](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) `Text.StringBuilder` and use it whenever needed;
- You create a file under `C:\Program Files`. Apart from the fact that that directory may have a different name on different versions of Windows (not to mention Linux, in case you're running on [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com)), users don't have permission to write there on any non-legacy (i.e. post-XP) versions of Windows. So, if you do this, your program will crash when distributed: if you [learn to use the proper file locations](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cjacks/archive/2008/02/05/where-should-i-write-program-data-instead-of-program-files.aspx) early on, that will save you lots of trouble.

Anyway, on to your question: whenever you want to create a string with lots of parameters and/or formatting, `String.Format` and its [custom format strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx) comes in extremely handy. For example, your original VB.NET code can be rewritten as follows:

```
Sub Form1_Load(s As Object, e As EventArgs)
  Using sw As New IO.StreamWriter(IO.Path.Combine(
            Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData),
            "maincode.txt"))
    sw.WriteLine("00000012{0:yyyyMMdd}{1}{0:HHmmss}", Now,
                 If((New Random).Next(0, 2) = 0, "0010", "0054"))
  End Using
End Sub
```

When executed, this should create `C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Roaming\maincode.txt` (or somewhere else if you're on XP or certain localized versions of Windows: check the value of `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)` in the debugger to find out).

Translating this to C# is trivial: if you use one of the many [VB.NET to C# translators available online](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/), it should give you something like this:

```
public void Form1_Load(object s, EventArgs e)
{
  using (System.IO.StreamWriter sw = new System.IO.StreamWriter(System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), "maincode.txt"))) {
    sw.WriteLine("00000012{0:yyyyMMdd}{1}{0:HHmmss}", DateAndTime.Now, (new Random()).Next(0, 2) == 0 ? "0010" : "0054");
  }
}
```

Basically, it added some semicolons and curly braces for you, included fully-qualified namespaces and rewrote the ternary condition: the .NET Framework bits are identical.

Hope this helps, and good luck with your programming efforts!

Comment: Well this was really just for my computer. However i have recently worked outy how to specify a folder through using the specialfolder. Thankyou for your opinions and links. I had no idea their was even a converter... Thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

Start with [creating Text files with C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bh11f1k.aspx) then go through [this tabel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_C_Sharp_and_Visual_Basic_.NET#Keywords) or [this one](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9978/Complete-Comparison-for-VB-NET-and-C) and rewrite your code in C# to build the information as described in your question.